# Terminating subprocess in python

Tags: python, django, subprocess

**Completely rewritten based on my own investigation**

I have a master script that runs a number of other python scripts.
The scripts are created as

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, Popen
from signal import SIGINT
import shlex
p = Popen(shlex.split("python somescript.py arg1 arg2"), cwd="../src/somedir", stderr=STDOUT)
```

And are terminated with

```
p.send_signal(SIGINT)
p.wait()
```

Inside them there is the following code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import signal
    def terminate(*args):
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, terminate)

    # do some work here
```

Each script has some function having

```
try:
    # create workers
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # cleanup, wait for the current worker to end, then return
```

All of the described works as supposed - the master script creates the processes, when it's execution ends, it sends them SIGINT, they handle it in the correct way, gracefully exiting.

Now, I want to run the Django dev server in the same way.

I altered the `manage.py` file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import signal
    def terminate(*args):
        print 'got SIGINT'
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, terminate)

    execute_manager(settings)
```

The `execute_manager` function after a number of calls leads to a django command method having the `except KeyboardInterrupt` block with `sys.exit(0)`. So, the whole setup looks the same.

The problem: the django server is not actually stopped, though I see the `got SIGINT` output.

**Probably an explanation:**

Looks like django manage.py forks itself, or does something similar; looking into Activity Monitor (the osx's processes explorer) I see 3 python processes started - the one for the master script, and, probably, 2 for manage.py. When terminating, 2 of them stop (the master script, and the one I have the link to with `p`), while the third remains continuing locking the 8000 port.
Is there a way to get process' subprocesses pids?

Comment: Why aren't you using `p.kill()`?

Comment: because the subprocesses are of specific structure, each having its handler for KeyboardInterrupt and making __gracefull__ exit (waiting to finish running jobs, for example)

Comment: Have you grepped Django's code to find `KeyboardInterrupt` and see how it (and related signals) are handled? Perhaps that would be illuminating -- just a thought! :)

Comment: yes, I did and found where it's caught. the reason was exactly in subprocess started in --reload mode - see Vinay's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) to find out about child processes, e.g. in pseudo-code:

```
p = Popen(...)
pp = psutil.Process(p.pid)
for child in pp.get_children():
    child.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

Note the difference in processes when running without --reload, obtained using `ps -ef | grep manage.py | grep -v grep`:

```
vinay 7864 7795  9 22:10 pts/0 00:00:00 python ./manage.py runserver
vinay 7865 7864 16 22:10 pts/0 00:00:00 /usr/bin/python ./manage.py runserver
```

compared with using the --noreload option:

```
vinay 7874 7795  7 22:10 pts/0 00:00:00 python ./manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: yes, I already notices the difference, though didn't know how to get children processes list. thank you, this helped.